# how to call function Keypress in the main java

Tags: java, function, program-entry-point, keypress, keyevent

so i've only this function `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` in my class and i'm trying to call it in the main but it doesn't work. i know i should not initialize KeyEvent with null but i don't know how to call it

```
public void  keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    switch(e.getKeyCode()) {

    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
         break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
         break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
         break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
         break;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
 Myclass class = new Myclass();
 KeyEvent KeyEvent = null;
 class.keyPressed(KeyEvent);
}
```

Comment: avoid using key words as variable names

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Update <sup>(for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550613/how-to-call-function-keypress-in-the-main-java/52550661#comment92040194_52550661))</sup> :**

You'll get a `NullPointerException` inside your `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` method because you haven't checked whether the passed argument is `null` or not before trying to access `e.getKeyCode();`.

Try parsing an `KeyEvent` object

```
Myclass c = new Myclass();
KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(new Component() {}, 0, 0l, 0, KeyEvent.VK_UP);
c.keyPressed(ke);
```

---

Avoid using keywords as variable names. Try this,

```
Myclass c = new Myclass();
c.keyPressed(null);
```

Comment: i have already done this but it doesnt work i've got java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Cristaline check the answer now

Comment: i've got an error while i 'm insialize KeyEvent  KeyEvent KeyEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1);

Comment: Use `new KeyEvent(new Component() {}, 0, 0l, 0, KeyEvent.VK_UP)` as I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: i've done this but i KeyEvent.VK_UP should have been initialized first :/

Comment: I'm sry I don't get you. `KeyEvent.VK_UP` is a `static int` from the class `KeyEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `null` value as a parameter to the function.

So  It will surely crash at

```
     int key = e.getKeyCode();
```

with a `NullPointerException` since `e` is `null` bacuse you can't call `getKeyCode()` on a `null` object

Try passing a valid `KeyEvent` object as parameter

Eg:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   Myclass myclass = new Myclass();
   KeyEvent KeyEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1);
   myclass.keyPressed(KeyEvent);
 }
```

Note: Replace `new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1);` with the code to find the keyEvent

Also if you want to prevent `NullPointerException`, put a null check in the `keyPressed` function as follows

```
 public void  keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e != null){
                int key = e.getKeyCode();

                switch(e.getKeyCode()) {

                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                     break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                     break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                     break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                     break;
            }
        }
```